# Can highcharts drilldown of a chart, reflect on another chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, drilldown

I've two separate div for charts, with ids  `container1` and `container2`, i am wondering if its possible to drilldown a stacked column in container1 and the result can show up in container2 where the stacked column in container1 remains the same.
Really appreciate your help.

```
<div id="container1" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/675kxe1q/

Here area chart shows up on drilldown in the same chart , is it possible to show it in different chart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you want is not a drilldown but to update a second chart with detailed data from the first chart. Have a look at [`point.events.click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cbar%3E.point.events.click). This will let you get the point that was clicked. From here you can update/set the data in a different chart.
Click event logic:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          detailChart(this.category);
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Then a general function that is going to create a new chart at `container2`:

```
  function detailChart(categoryName) {
    $('#container2').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week5']
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          point: {
            events: {
              click: function() {
                detailChart(this.category);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },

      series: [{
        data: [10, 20, 5, 4.9]
      }]
    });
  }
```

You can key off of anything not just `this.category` and set up your detail series as an array of data that is linked to your click key.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to add the detail series in the function detailChart for `container2` fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xynzs6hb/  ,but the extended series for all the categories is shown in the second chart. Can you please suggest a way to show particular series when its clicked in chart1?

Comment: @Disera, you need to remove the drilldown.js library and then click on the bar. If you want to add click action on `xAxis` labels that is doable as well (see SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446970/add-event-to-x-axis-labels-of-bar-highchart).

Answer (score 2):

I think that the most efficient solution is using default drilldown, then catch drilldown event where you extract drilled series from `e.seriesOptions` object and return false value (to stop event). Next step is run the new chart with reference to series.

```
    chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events:{
                drilldown: function(e) {
                e.seriesOptions.color = e.point.color;
                detailChart(e.seriesOptions);
                return false;
              }
            }
        },
//....

  function detailChart(series) {
    console.log('d', series);
      $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'area'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week5']
        },

        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
              events: {
                click: function() {
                  detailChart(this.category);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },

        series: [series]
      });
    }
});
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/wasdf21b/

Comment: Thank you! In your fiddle, all the columns in the chart are clickable once, and not able to click the same column again. can you please explain why is that?